# Why is my section doesn't fit my website?

Tags: html, css

It doesn't fit at all, how do I fix it

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBI4n.png)

CSS:

```
.welcome {
  background-color: #9dbbf8;
  color: #1b1b1b;
  height: 760px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as for now, there is no way we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that the div thing touches the edges the basic is that websites already have margin and padding. The easiest method is by removing it like this:

```css
 * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

.welcome {
        background-color: #9dbbf8;
        color: #1b1b1b;
        height: 760px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
     }
```

```html
<div class="welcome"></div>
```

Hope you like my answer.

Answer (score -1):

In most browsers, the `body` tag has a default margin set on it. So the solution would be to remove that margin:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Also, it is a good practice to apply some basic styles to HTML elements to make them render in different browsers more consistently. A great tool for that would be to use  [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or other CSS resets.